# Which logger is outputting this in gunicorn?

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn

When I start gunicorn it prints this:

```
[2018-11-09 16:30:20 +0000] [16] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-11-09 16:30:20 +0000] [16] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (16)
[2018-11-09 16:30:20 +0000] [16] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-11-09 16:30:20 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
```

Setting up a logger for the gunicorn package (propagating) doesn't seem to affect it. What module is the one I should configure to modify these messages?

Answer (score 1):

Those messages are output by the `Arbiter` class in `gunicorn/arbiter.py`, but it may be that any configuring you try and do is overridden by gunicorn's machinery, or not applicable - for example, trying to set up logging in a worker won't affect what the arbiter does, as they are separate processes. So you may need to invoke the arbiter in a special way (i.e. not just through running a canned `gunicorn` script) if you want to affect its logging, or amend the gunicorn configuration used for the arbiter.